# Constructor invocation in the inherited class

Tags: java

This is a very basic question on Java. I've read somewhere that at first in the subclass's constructor the constructor of the super class is implicitly called. But I couldn't find the reference to the documentation, to read about that in detail. Could someone please provide this reference?

Here is an example of what I'm talking about, that outputs the `super sub` string:

```
class SuperClass {
    static String s = "";
    protected SuperClass() { s += "super "; }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    private SubClass() { s += "sub"; }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SubClass();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no *overriding* of constructors in Java - they're not called polymorphically to start with.

But each constructor has to call a constructor of the superclass, either implicitly (calling a parameterless one) or explicitly (with `super(...)` as the first line of the constructor body - *or* chain to another constructor within the same class, with `this(...)` as the first line of the constructor body. The chained constructor is executed before the rest of the constructor body.

See [section 8.8.7 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7) for more details.

Comment: You are right, I've changed the wording to the "subclass's constructor" before reading your answer. Thank you for the link.